# How to move comboBox to the bottom of its it's vertical layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox, qlayout

In my program when a push button is pressed, I need the comboBox at the top of the verticalLayout to move down to the bottom so the 2nd comboBox is at the top. The comboBoxes have been created in Qt designer and I need this to be able to be done multiple times in one instance of the application. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: How many combobox do you have? What should happen if you press the button a second time?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have 15 comboBoxes. I could manually make the text of each box be set to the text of the box below it but I feel there should be an easier or more efficient way. When it is pressed a second time it, the comboBox that is at the top at that point in time should move to the bottom and all the rest get moved up one place.

Comment: @eyllanesc Is there a way to move the actual combobox instead of just shifting its contents or should I just change the contents of each box to the one below it?

Comment: you could put a more concrete example, what you indicate can be interpreted in many ways, for example let's say you have combobox A, B, C and D, what should be the order if you press 1, 2 and 3 the button for example.

Comment: the simplest solution is to remove the QComboBox from the layout and reinsert it into the new position, since if you copy the content you could lose internal states of the QComboBox that are not part of the content.

Comment: @eyllanesc If it is pressed once the order would be BCDA, twice would be CDAB thrice would be DABC etc. How do I remove the QComboBox fro the layout and reinsert it into a new position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166573/discussion-between-abhi-garg-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets can not be moved freely within the layout, the layout manages the position and size of the widgets. The strategy to obtain that displacement is to remove the widget from the first position and reinsert it:

```
QLayoutItem *child;
// remove
if ((child = ui->verticalLayout->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
    // insert
    ui->verticalLayout->addItem(child);
}
```

You can find a complete example in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49203661)